True SMT divergence indicator
I am trying to build real smt divergence indicator. The ones on tradingview arent good. I have the code for the fractal indicator, which marks out, in real time, proper lows and highs. I want to add something like this to it :
Bullish Divergence:
Compare lows between two different symbols (e.g., US500 and US100).
The condition occurs when:
On the current chart, one low is higher than the next low.
On the comparison chart (e.g., SP500), the same low is lower than the next low.
Similarly, if on the current chart one low is lower than the next low, the comparison chart's low should be higher than the next low.
Bearish Divergence:
    Compare highs between two different symbols.
    The condition occurs when:
        On the current chart, one high is lower than the next high.
        On the comparison chart (e.g., SP500), the same high is higher than the next high.
    Similarly, if on the current chart one high is higher than the next high, the comparison chart's high should be lower than the next high.

The indicator should draw lines connecting the respective highs or lows that meet the divergence criteria. These lines should be clear and distinguishable for bullish and bearish divergence.

The comparison should be based on fractal points (swing highs/lows) on both charts.

In summary, you wanted an SMT divergence indicator that compares fractals between the current chart and another selected symbol, identifying and highlighting only divergences where the relative position of highs or lows between the two symbols reverses.
Here is the code for the fractals i use (also detects FVGs) :
indicator('Moj FVG i Fractals', overlay = true)

// === FVG Inputs ===
fvg_border_color = input.color(color.yellow, "FVG Border Color")
fvg_bg_color = input.color(color.new(color.yellow, 90), "FVG Bg Color")
fvg_bar_color = input.color(color.yellow, "FVG Bar Color")

// === FVG Logic ===
fvg_up_gap = close[1] > open[1] ? low - high[2] : na
fvg_down_gap = close[1] < open[1] ? low[2] - high : na

fvg_up_box = fvg_up_gap > 0 ? box.new(left = bar_index[2], top = high[2], right = bar_index, bottom = low, border_color = fvg_border_color, bgcolor = fvg_bg_color) : na
fvg_down_box = fvg_down_gap > 0 ? box.new(left = bar_index[2], top = low[2], right = bar_index, bottom = high, border_color = fvg_border_color, bgcolor = fvg_bg_color) : na

// === Bar Colors for FVG ===
barcolor(fvg_up_gap > 0 ? fvg_bar_color : na, offset = -1)
barcolor(fvg_down_gap > 0 ? fvg_bar_color : na, offset = -1)

// === Fractal Inputs ===
showPatterns = input(true, "Show Fractal Patterns")
filterBW = input(false, title="Bill Williams Fractals Filter")

// === Fractal Recognition Functions ===
isRegularFractal(mode) =>
    mode == 1 ? high[4] < high[3] and high[3] < high[2] and high[2] > high[1] and high[1] > high[0] :mode == -1 ? low[4] > low[3] and low[3] > low[2] and low[2] < low[1] and low[1] < low[0] : false

isBWFractal(mode) =>
    mode == 1 ? high[4] < high[2] and high[3] <= high[2] and high[2] >= high[1] and high[2] > high[0] :mode == -1 ? low[4] > low[2] and low[3] >= low[2] and low[2] <= low[1] and low[2] < low[0] : false

filteredtopf = filterBW ? isRegularFractal(1) : isBWFractal(1)
filteredbotf = filterBW ? isRegularFractal(-1) : isBWFractal(-1)

// === Plot Fractals ===
plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Filtered Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, offset=-2)
plotshape(filteredbotf, title='Filtered Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, offset=-2)```

